# Nutch 2.3.1 on Yarn 2.7.1 error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, nutch

Has anyone managed to run Nutch 2.3.1 on a Hadoop 2 cluster? I have been trying to run Nutch 2.3.1 on my Hadoop/Yarn 2.7.1 cluster for about two days now.

First of all, my Nutch is installed only locally and not on all nodes. I set HBase to be the storage engine.

Initially, downloading and trying it on the cluster was failing because it could not find some libraries at the workers side, which I resolved by modifying the `runtime/local/bin/nutch` script to include all the libraries when sending the jar to be executed:

```
LIBJARS="$NUTCH_HOME"/lib/apache-nutch-2.3.1.jar
for f in "$NUTCH_HOME"/lib/*.jar; do
   LIBJARS="${LIBJARS},$f";
done

# run it
exec "${EXEC_CALL[@]}" $CLASS -libjars $LIBJARS "$@"
```

However, after resolving this, I am encountering the following error which I don't know how to resolve:

```
InjectorJob: starting at 2016-05-11 10:37:46
InjectorJob: Injecting urlDir: /user/ubuntu/urls
InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore as the Gora storage class.
Error: org.apache.gora.util.GoraException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.gora.mapreduce.GoraOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(GoraOutputFormat.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:767)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:132)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:630)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:493)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:442)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:865)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.readMapping(HBaseStore.java:719)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:116)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:535)
    ... 25 more

Error: org.apache.gora.util.GoraException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.gora.mapreduce.GoraOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(GoraOutputFormat.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:767)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:132)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:630)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:493)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:442)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:865)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.readMapping(HBaseStore.java:719)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:116)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:535)
    ... 25 more

Error: org.apache.gora.util.GoraException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.gora.mapreduce.GoraOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(GoraOutputFormat.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewDirectOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:767)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:132)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:630)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:493)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:442)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:518)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:865)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.readMapping(HBaseStore.java:719)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:116)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:535)
    ... 25 more

InjectorJob: java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=apache-nutch-2.3.1.jar, jobid=job_1462952885071_0009
    at org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:119)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:231)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.inject(InjectorJob.java:252)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.run(InjectorJob.java:275)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.InjectorJob.main(InjectorJob.java:284)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. First of all, I was trying to execute the `runtime/local/bin scripts`, which will not work on cluster. The correct scripts to run in this case are the ones in `runtime/deploy/bin`. According to nutch wiki

*The Nutch job jar you find in $NUTCH_HOME/runtime/deploy is self containing and ships with all the configuration files necessary for Nutch to be able to run on any vanilla Hadoop cluster. All you need is a healthy cluster and a Hadoop environment (cluster or local) that points to the jobtracker.*

Also, and very importantly, in order to correctly build nutch for distributed mode, the nutch-site.xml configuration **should not contain** the setting for plugin.folders. Mine contains

```
<property>
 <name>http.agent.name</name>
 <value>Sofia's Nutch Spider</value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>storage.data.store.class</name>
 <value>org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore</value>
</property>

<!-- If this is not set to -1, then big pages might not be scanned till the end -->
<property>
 <name>http.content.limit</name>
 <value>-1</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>file.crawl.parent</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:8020</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>hadoop-master</value>
</property>
 <property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
  <value>hadoop-master:8032</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
  <value> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
  <value>hadoop-master:8031</value>
 </property>
 <property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
  <value>hadoop-master:8030</value>
 </property>
```